Lifetime of a Reference Bound Temporary - Visual C++ bug?
From standard: "The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except..." (exceptions seems not to apply). An example from the standard that works fine:
struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
S a { 1, {2,3} };

If I add a constructor, the referenced object is destructed after S is instantiated. Am I missing something?
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// added just to catch the destructor call
struct Pair : public pair<int, int>
{
  Pair() : pair<int, int>{ 1, 2 } {}
  ~Pair() { cout << "~Pair\n"; }
};

struct S
{
  const Pair& mp;
  S(const Pair& p) : mp{ p } {}
  void print() const { cout << mp.first << ' ' << mp.second << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
  S p{ Pair() }; // outputs "~Pair"
  p.print(); // outputs "1 2"; ub, probably
}


If you add a constructor, the temp is bound to the constructor parameter. The binding is not passed on to the member.

S p{ Pair() }; // outputs "~Pair": The temporary instance of Pair exists until the end of the full expression. This is the end of the initialization i.e. at the location of the semicolon.

@BoP You are probably referring to "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits." To me it means: C():ra{A()}{}, but I could be wrong.

Without the constructor S(), it would work: Modified demo on coliru.

@BoP All the compilers I've checked give the same result (they even output the same values), so I think you're right, but the reason behind this exception eludes me.

The very first exception applies; "A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (7.6.1.3) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call."

@molbdnilo I'm not sure a constructor qualifies as a regular member function.

@zdf: What’s a “regular member function”?  But that doesn’t matter—it is a function call of some kind, isn’t it?  (Perhaps the cross reference to [expr.call] is doing more harm than good there.)

Re: the reason for this exception. Consider: struct S { int& x; }; S* f() { int y = 42; return new S{y}; } So, y lives on the stack as a local variable inside f. The instance of S lives who knows how long. How do you expect the compiler to extend the lifetime of y to outlive the heap-allocated instance of S? Where would the memory to hold it come from? Practically speaking, lifetime of a temporary can be extended from "current full expression" to "enclosing block", but not beyond.

@IgorTandetnik Your point is valid. However, this is an exception already specified in standard and does not apply on my case. In my example, in both cases, the subobject, as well as the object are created on the stack.

@zdf So you say a temporary bound to a reference member of a class should have its lifetime extended sometimes but not always, depending on how that class instance itself is created. Yes if on a stack; no if on a heap. What if it's not a standalone instance but in turn a member of another class? The initialization of that reference member could be buried down a chain of constructors, for which the compiler may not even see the source. Should it be "only if the object of a class is directly created as a local variable, and the constructor is inline"? Now that would be an awfully specific case.

@IgorTandetnik I agree that things can get very complicated, but I'm just repeating what the standard says. I'm not the smartest person around, so I may have misinterpreted.

Ah, I think I misunderstood the question. You are asking why the behavior differs depending on the presence of a constructor. When S has a constructor, the reference that is being bound to the temporary is the parameter of the constructor, which is destroyed once the constructor returns. Withouth the constructor you are doing aggregate initialization, and binding the temporary directly to the class member. There is an explicit exception for the case where new is invloved: new S{ Pair() } doesn't extend the lifetime of the temporary.

If you are asking why the standard couldn't make the "with constructor" case work - well, I don't think this could be reasonably implemented. The constructor could be implemented in a separate file. If all the compiler sees is struct S { S(int& r); int& m; }; how is it supposed to know that whatever is bound to r would eventually end up being bound to m? And you don't want the meaning of the program to silently change just by moving the constructor's body from the header to the source file.
